# When integer rings are Euclidean domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

**Definition** A Euclidean domain is an integral domain R, together with a map $f: R \backslash \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{>=0},$ such that   $\forall a, b\in R$ with $b\neq 0:\ \exists q,r \in R:\ a = bq+r$ and either $r = 0$ or $f(r) < f(b)$.

**Claim** $\mathbb{Z}[\sigma]$ is an Euclidean domain, where $\sigma = \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$.

**Proof attempt**
For $\alpha = a+b\sigma \in \mathbb{Z}[\sigma]\backslash\{0\}$, let $f(\alpha) = a^2 - ab - b^2$. Notice that $f$ commutes with products. Now take an arbitrary $\beta = c+d\sigma \in \mathbb{Z}[\sigma]$. We will express $\beta = \alpha \gamma + \theta$ for $\gamma \in \mathbb{Z}[\sigma]$ s.t. either $\theta=0$ or $f(\theta) < f(\alpha)$.
So consider $\beta/\alpha = r + s \sigma \in \mathbb{Q}[\sigma]$ for $r,s \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Let $k, l\in \mathbb{Z}$ be closest integers to $r,s$ respectively, so that 
$|k-r|\leq\frac{1}{2}$ and $|l-s|\leq\frac{1}{2}$. Additionally, let $\gamma = k+l\sigma,\ m = r-k,\ n =s-l,\ \theta=(a+b\sigma)(m+n\sigma)$.

Then by construction we have
$$\begin{align}c + d\sigma &= (a+b\sigma)(r+s\sigma)\\ &= (a+b\sigma)(k+l\sigma)+(a+b\sigma)(m+n\sigma)\end{align}$$
Ie. $\beta = \alpha\gamma + \theta$. Now assume $\theta \neq 0$. We have that 
$$\begin{align} f(\theta) &= f(a+b\sigma)\cdot f(m+n\sigma)\\ &= (a^2 - ab - b^2) (m^2 - mn - n^2)\\ &\leq (a^2-ab-b^2)(1/4+1/4+1/4)\\ &\leq \frac{3}{4}(a^2 -ab -b^2)\\ &\leq f(\alpha)\end{align}$$

**Questions**

1. Is the above proof attempt OK?
2. If so, why is it that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ is not a PID?

Comment: OK, @DietrichBurde, I had a look, so did I make a similar mistake, ie that my f is not integer valued on this ring? I mean it looks integer valued to me. Other than that, why would it matter if it really is the integer ring of $\mathbb{Q}[\sigma]$ or not?

Comment: As a ring of integers it would be a Dedekind ring, hence a PID if and only if it is factorial. However, $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{5}]$ is not the ring of integers, as lhf already told you.

Comment: @DietrichBurde this is a little bit beyond me frankly. If I don't insist on interpreting it as a ring of integers, would it be Euclidean?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, my question above refers to $\mathbb{Z}[\sigma]$. I now understand why $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ is not a PID. So I'd just like to establish if my above proof is correct or not?

Comment: The why did you questions 1. and 2. together? Perhaps you can edit the question and only ask for the proof. You also can look at the standard proof for this and compare yourself.

Comment: Well, @DietrichBurde, my understanding evolves with time... When I posted the two together, I found the situation somewhat paradoxical. Thanks to lhf's answer I now understand why there's no paradox here. Given that an answer has been posted, I'd rather not edit my question substantially, especially as I wanted both 1 & 2 answered. As a side-note, with the same amount of effort (that is invested into being pedagogical) you could also be helpful at the same time, and that would in the end provide me with a better educational experience.

Comment: I think that all is fine, then. The questions have been answered, and your proof looks OK. At least, I see no reason why to look more closely. Perhaps someone else has done the same calculations and can give you more advice.

Answer (score 2):

One reason $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ is not a PID is that it is not integrally closed. (*)

Indeed, $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ is a root of $x^2 + x - 1$ but it is not in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$.

(*) We have PID $\implies$ UFD $\implies$ integrally closed.

Comment: So is the above proof correct, ie is $Z[\sigma]$ a PID?

Comment: Your $Z[\sigma]$ is the ring of integers of $Q(\sqrt 5)$, hence is known to be a PID. There is a short list of quadratic fields $Q(\sqrt m), m=2,3,5,6,7,173,293,437$, for which the rings of integers are PID in exercise 6 of chapter 5 of D. Marcus' "Number Fields". As for euclidianity w.r.t. to the *norm function*, the full list for $m>0$ is known: the rings of integers are norm-euclidian iff $m=2,3,5,6,7,11,13,17,19,21,29,33,37,41,57,73$; see e.g. F. Lemmermeyer, "The euclidian algorithm in algebraic number fields". Of course other positive examples could exist for other types of functions.

Comment: @nguyenquangdo thank you for your comment, this is very interesting